# How to maintain same session across multiple requests in rest-assured?

Tags: rest, web-services, rest-assured, web-api-testing

Pre-req:Rest-assured api tests with Java

**Step** 
**1. Launch URL and get login ticket** - code snippet below to get login ticket

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://ve4al10p:453";
RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
Response res = 
   given().
        header("Content-Type","application/json").
    when().
        post("/i/login?action=lt").
    then().
        assertThat().statusCode(200).
        extract().response();
    res.prettyPrint();
```

Output: Notice login ticket

**`lt":"LT-12370-j4znjFQkGMXMjlT3uKJ"`**

**Step 2. Use login ticket and perform login with username and password.** 
I extracted login ticket and passed to next request (continued snippet).

```
 CookieFilter cookieFilter = new CookieFilter();
 Response res1 = given(). 
    filter(cookieFilter).
    header("Content-Type","application/json").
    queryParam("lt",loginticket). 
    queryParam("username","user1"). 
    queryParam("password","pass1"). 
when().
    post("/i/login?service=https://ve4al10p:443/spa").  
then().
    assertThat().statusCode(200).
    extract().response();
res1.prettyPrint();
```

**Output: Notice it again creates a new login ticket, that means a new session and fails give expected output.**

```
**"lt":"LT-12369-u6osMkesdg6RQu9JPoDARL4D"**
```

Note: I also noticed the sessions for above requests and both are different.

**Expected Output:** I want to use same login ticket and maintain same sessions.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the SessionID/cookie from login and pass this as SessionID to next request as header to maintain single session.

for eg :

```
String JsessionID = given().header(h1).body(payload).when().post(basepath).thenReturn().cookie("JSESSIONID");
given().headers(JsessionID).body(body).when().post();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about send request with cookie?
Let's say you got access_token in cookie after login success, you can send request within the access_token in cookie:

```
String token = given()
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .body(payload)
    .log()
    .all()
.when()
    .post(loginUrl)
    .thenReturn()
    .cookie("access_token");

Cookie tokenCookie = new Cookie.Builder("access_token", token)
    .setSecured(true)
    .setComment("some comment")
    .build();

assertEquals(given()
    .cookie(tokenCookie)
    .when()
    .get(nextRequest)
    .statusCode(), 200);
```